# Unclosed statement driving me crazy

Tags: java, prepared-statement, jboss7.x

I have this code:

```
      Helper helper = getDBhelper();

      Connection conn = helper.getConnection();

      String sql = 
              " SELECT DISTINCT date as plannedDate" +
              " FROM plan ";

      String AssimilationTabDates = 
              " SELECT DISTINCT payment as plannedDate " +
              " FROM credit_mo_assimilation_tab ";

      String assimilationInfoDates = 
              " SELECT DISTINCT planned_pay as plannedDate " +
              " FROM assimilation ";


      String sqlUpdate = 
               " UPDATE plan " +
               " SET date = ? " +
               " WHERE planned_date = ? ";

      String updateAssimilationTab = 
              " UPDATE assimilation " +
              " SET payment = to_date(?, 'DD-MM-YYYY') " +
              " WHERE d_payment = to_date(?, 'DD-MM-YYYY') ";

      String updateAssimilationInfo = 
              " UPDATE assimilation " +
              " SET pay = to_date(?, 'DD-MM-YYYY') " +
              " WHERE planned_pay = ? ";



        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Date plannedDate = null;
        List<String> plannedDates = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> plannedTabDates = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> plannedInfoDates = new ArrayList<String>();

      try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()) {
                  plannedDate = rs.getDate("plannedDate");  
                  String plannedD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(plannedDate);
                  plannedDates.add(plannedD);
            }

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(AssimilationTabDates);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()) {
                  plannedDate = rs.getDate("plannedDate");  
                  String plannedD = null;
                  if(plannedDate != null){
                      plannedD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(plannedDate);
                  }
                  if(plannedD != null){
                      plannedTabDates.add(plannedD);
                  }

            }

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(assimilationInfoDates);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()) {
                  plannedDate = rs.getDate("plannedDate");  
                  String plannedD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(plannedDate);
                  plannedInfoDates.add(plannedD);
            }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } 


      try{
          for( String oneItem : plannedDates ) {
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
              Date datePlanned = formatter.parse(oneItem);
              Date paymentDate = datePlanned;

              Date paymentDateReal = paymentDate;

              if (paymentDate != null) {

                    paymentDateReal = DefaultProdCalendar.findNearestWorkingDay(paymentDate); 
            }

            String realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(paymentDateReal);



                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
                ps.setString(1, realDate);
                ps.setString(2, oneItem);
                ps.execute();
                rs = ps.getResultSet();
            }

          for( String oneItem : plannedTabDates ) {
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
              Date datePlanned = formatter.parse(oneItem);
              Date paymentDate = datePlanned;

              Date paymentDateReal = paymentDate;

              if (paymentDate != null) {
                  paymentDateReal = DefaultProdCalendar.findNearestWorkingDay(paymentDate);
            }

            String realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(paymentDateReal);



                ps = conn.prepareStatement(updateAssimilationTab);
                ps.setString(1, realDate);
                ps.setString(2, oneItem);
                ps.execute();
                rs = ps.getResultSet();
            }

          for( String oneItem : plannedInfoDates ) {
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
              Date datePlanned = formatter.parse(oneItem);
              Date paymentDate = datePlanned;

              Date paymentDateReal = paymentDate;

              if (paymentDate != null) {
                  paymentDateReal = DefaultProdCalendar.findNearestWorkingDay(paymentDate);
            }

            String realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(paymentDateReal);



                ps = conn.prepareStatement(updateAssimilationInfo);
                ps.setString(1, realDate);
                ps.setString(2, oneItem);
                ps.execute();
                rs = ps.getResultSet();
            }


      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }



      try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()) {
                  plannedDate = rs.getDate("plannedDate");  
                  String plannedD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(plannedDate);
                  plannedDates.add(plannedD);
            }

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(AssimilationTabDates);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()) {
                  plannedDate = rs.getDate("plannedDate");  
                  String plannedD = null;
                  if(plannedDate != null){
                      plannedD  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(plannedDate);
                  }

                  if(plannedD != null){
                      plannedTabDates.add(plannedD);
                  }
            }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } 


      try{
          for( String oneItem : plannedDates ) {
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
              Date datePlanned = formatter.parse(oneItem);
              Date paymentDate = datePlanned;

              Date paymentDateReal = paymentDate;

              if (paymentDate != null) {
                  paymentDateReal = DefaultProdCalendar.findNearestWorkingDay(paymentDate);
            }

            String realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(paymentDateReal);



                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
                ps.setString(1, realDate);
                ps.setString(2, oneItem);
                ps.execute();
                rs = ps.getResultSet();
            }

          for( String oneItem : plannedTabDates ) {
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
              Date datePlanned = formatter.parse(oneItem);
              Date paymentDate = datePlanned;

              Date paymentDateReal = paymentDate;

              if (paymentDate != null) {
                  paymentDateReal = DefaultProdCalendar.findNearestWorkingDay(paymentDate);
            }

            String realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(paymentDateReal);

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(updateAssimilationTab);
                ps.setString(1, realDate);
                ps.setString(2, oneItem);
                ps.execute();
                rs = ps.getResultSet();
            }


      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }   
      finally {
          try {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

The above code runs perfectly fine, but there is a small issue. The statement is not getting closed, so this is pushing my `jboss` server to do it and it throws the following error for almost all the query executions:

```
Closing a statement you left open, please do your own housekeeping: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
```

Aren't

```
ps.close();
conn.close();
```

In the `finally` supposed to close everything up?

I know that I'm missing something extremely small and simple, but I'm not able to spot it right now.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using `try-with-resources`...

Comment: I'd strongly suggest turning each of these into separate methods.  Seeing all those try/catch blocks in a single method makes me ill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You keep creating new prepared statements and assigning them to `ps`, but you only ever close the last one. If you're needing to execute a sequence of statements, either close them as you go or put them in separate variables so you can close them all at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If we agree that a method should do one thing well, I'd say this is a bad implementation.

Each of those SQL operations ought to have a separate method.  Each `try/catch/finally` should create and close resources in the narrowest scope possible (method scope).

You can't have commit/rollback logic if you acquire the `Connection`.  I'd suggest passing it into your SQL methods.  Let a service or business layer, that knows about units of work, acquire the `Connection` and commit or rollback.

I'd also say you're repeating a lot of code unnecessarily.  I'd refactor to make this DRY-er.

Comment: This is good and correct advice but really doesn't address the question.

Comment: I think it does.  The multiple instances in a single method reflects the misunderstanding about having those closed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what chrylis said, your exception handling is flawed. When you catch an exception, it won't propagate to the enclosing `try/catch`. So you should replace your catch-clauses with this:

```
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace(); // I'd also replace this by something useful (ie. logging)
  } finally {
      ps.close();
  }
```